# Get tornado cookie expires in back-end

Tags: tornado

I can not get the cookie expire days in tornado. Could somebody know about this?

Note: get_cookie and get_secure_cookie is used to get the value of the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ordinary cookies, you cannot read the expiration time - it's simply not sent as a part of the cookie protocol. All you get is the value. That value, however, can be whatever you want, so you can encode the expiration time into the value to make it accessible on the server (this is what Tornado's secure cookies do, although the expiration time used there is not exposed to the application). I recommend json-encoding a dictionary to make the cookie value.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado uses `http.cookies.Cookie.SimpleCookie` to parse cookies in the request header. This creates a dictionary of `http.cookies.Morsel`  instances (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html?highlight=cookies#morsel-objects) which contain information about each cookie.

You can access the list of cookies against your `RequestHandler`'s `request` property, e.g:

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        for cookie_key in self.request.cookies.keys():
            cookie = self.request.cookies[cookie_key]
            print(cookie_key, cookie['expires'], cookie.output())
```

I've tested this on a tornado instance running locally and this does output details about the cookie to the console, however the `expires` date is not passed by the browser (chromium) in the request to the server and so it cannot be retrieved.

I don't see any guaranteed way to extract information about the `expires` date in this way, you could potentially use JavaScript to extract the `expires` date (which is available client side) and store it in an additional cookie (e.g `my_cookie` holds the value, and `my_cookie_expires` holds the `expires` date for `my_cookie`). I'm sure this isn't an ideal solution, but depending on how critical a resolution to this problem is it might be an option.